# Not able to access Kunstmaan admin panel

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I have installed Kunstmaan Bundles Standard Edition as per documentation :http://bundles.kunstmaan.be/getting-started/installation

and now i want to open admin panel but its giving me 503 Service Unavailable error message ..

Please help!!

Comment: Can add any more information? There's not much to go on here.

Comment: Are you sure you configured your website correctly? We kept that out of the docs, as we assume developers know how to do this. Refer to the Symfony docs : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html. If this is the issue, just leave a comment and I'll update the docs accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to use this url:

```
http://localhost/pathtourl/web/app_dev.php/en/login
```

Regards